# Display a Splash Screen Before Loading the Root Navigation Controller - iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am new bee in iPhone. I have implmented using some tutorials, a Splash Screen before loading the UIViewController. Now i want to implement a NavigationController in my application and want to display a Splash Screen before it. Since I am new in Iphone so i did not get any tutotrials or guides to make a Splash Screen before loading a Root Navigation Controller.

I have seen many methods in which they over write the Default.png file and so on. I dont want to implement that one. I want a sperate UIView to have my custom Images and text in it and display that UI View as a Splash Screen

can anybody Guide me please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go buddy. Have fun and happy coding....

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
//Add a splash screen
    UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"]];
    imgv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [navigationController.view addSubview:imgv];
    [imgv release];

    [self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash:) withObject:imgv afterDelay:3.0];

    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    return YES;
}



- (void)removeSplash:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: can u please demonstrate me step by step.. Kindly. m new in it

Comment: ok what I'm doing here is initializing a new uiimageview object and adding it navigation controller's view. and then after 3 seconds i'm removing that uiimageview.

Comment: Please can u show it step by step that which views should be made before that and which UINavigation Controller should be created and added. You know like a tutorial

Comment: you need to put this code in application did finish launching method. This code will display an splash screen for 3 seconds before your actual view(the first view) will displayed which in navigation controller.

Comment: this will display a splash screen before loading a Root Navigation Controller.

Comment: you need to add a navigation controller to your app delegate's header file. Initialize it and pass it a rootView controller. and then put the code I have posted all in applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: Thanks alot friend .. i am done with your guidelines.... altough instead of UIImageView i used UIView .. Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

Use "**self.window**" to display the splash image first. If u simply write "**window**", the image will not be displayed and animated in the first view, since the image can't be directly linked to the window in that case. Write the following code in **appdelegate.m**

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions         
    {
           self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"themes.png"]];
        imgv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.navigationController.view addSubview:imgv];
        //[imgv release]; If you don't use ARC, uncomment this.

        [self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash:) withObject:imgv afterDelay:3.0];
        [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

        return YES;
    }

- (void)removeSplash:(UIImageView *)imageView 
  {
       [imageView removeFromSuperview];
  }
```